# call a function in a closure using call or apply?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a loose augmentation closure which contains some functions I want to access [vastly simplified]

```
var Process = (function(Process,$){
    _thing1 = function(a,b,c) {
         return a + b + c;
    }
    _thing2 = function(a,b,c) {
         return $(a).html(b + c);
    }
    return {
       Fred: {
          Add: _thing1
       },
       Bob: {
          Add: _thing2
       }
     }
}(Process || {},jQuery));
```

I can invoke the function directly

```
var foo = Process.Fred.Add(1,2,3);
```

If I have a string representation in an object of the function name I want to call and some arguments, how do I call it?

```
var data = {
    "function": "Process.Fred.Add",
    "params": [1,2,3]
}
```

I can't use `data.function.apply(data.function.params)` since it results in a typeerror.

Comment: You could use `Proccess[data.function].apply(data.params)`. You cant use an apply on a String

Comment: But this would be `Process["Process.Fred.Add"].apply(...`

Comment: Yes, you would change to something clean than this `Proccess[data.function.split('.')[1]][data.function.split('.')[2]].apply(data.params)` but this is the essence. Eval is so unsafe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Process is in the global scope, you can walk the tree to get the reference to the method so you can execute it.

```js
var Process = (function(Process, $) {
  _thing1 = function(a, b, c) {
    return a + b + c;
  }
  _thing2 = function(a, b, c) {
    return $(a).html(b + c);
  }
  return {
    Fred: {
      Add: _thing1
    },
    Bob: {
      Add: _thing2
    }
  }
}(Process || {}, jQuery));

var data = {
  "function": "Process.Fred.Add",
  "params": [1, 2, 3]
}

var result = data.function.split(/\./g)         //break up string into pieces
               .reduce((o, k) => o[k], window)  //walk the tree to get method reference
                 .apply(this, data.params);     //execute the method with the parameters
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If it is not in global scope, than you need to put `Process` in somewhere you can reference.

EG: An object

```
var myStuff = { "Process: : {} }
```

than the reduce line would be

...reduce((o, k) => o[k], myStuff)

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate your string first:

```js
eval(data.function).apply(data.function.params)
```

But [don't use eval needlessly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!), as [eval is evil](http://xkr.us/js/eval).